# Spring Boot Actuator -- purpose of the `/actuators/features` endpoint in the spring boot actuator

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

So I created a basic spring boot webapp with the IntelliJ Spring Boot Initializer (I believe Spring Boot 3.0.2).  I included the actuator then set it up with all of the endpoints.  There was a `/actuator/features` endpoint in the list of mappings.

```
"features": {
  "href": "http://localhost:8080/actuator/features",
  "templated": false
}
```

when I went to that endpoint it returned this:

```
{
  "enabled": [
    {
      "type": 
      "org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.composite.CompositeDiscoveryClient",
      "name": "DiscoveryClient",
      "version": "4.1.0",
      "vendor": "Pivotal Software, Inc."
    }
  ],
  "disabled": [
    "LoadBalancerClient"
  ]
}
```

What are these, how can I create my own?  Is there any documentation that answers these questions?  What did I miss?